# Redirect loop from old domain to new subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, loops

I have an issue with .htaccess rewrite ruleset. www.OldDomain.com with Joomla template is being retired and new website is a Wordpress based site having address at http://newdomain.com/subfolder.

For some reason I get the following message: "This webpage has a redirect loop", but whatever I try it doesn't work. The new Wordpress site has url-friendly links generated by wordpress. I tried to upload a default wordpress .htaccess but it doesn't work either.

Can anyone point me in right direction how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

The old site was on a different server with the same domain name as the new one.

Current .htaccess file on a domains' new server is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ beta/ [L]
```

Comment: Post the htaccess files of the old and new domains

Comment: I am not allowed to put the rest of htacces as I am new at SO so it goes like this:

redirect 301 http://www.OldDomain.com/index.php?option=com_contact&Itemid=3 http://newdomain.com/
redirect 301 http://www.OldDomain.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=49 http://newdomain.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/beta/$1 [L,R=301]
```